# How to make an ActionBar on React Native?

Tags: react-native, android-actionbar, expo

I am trying to create an action Bar in the top of my app, which I created with Expo. Previously, I only worked with Android Studio, which created the bar automatically.

I attempted using the Toolbar component, which did not show up in the test run

```
<ToolbarAndroid
  title="Login"
  actions={[{title: 'Settings', show: 'always'}]}/>
```

By Action Bar, I mean the bar circled in the image below. I am pretty sure the name is Action bar, but I might be wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been addressed [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5293#issuecomment-296615965).

You need to specify both the width and height of the ToolbarAndroid.